# measure to establish closeness of step functions to some curve

Tags: statistics, euclidean-geometry, arithmetic, geometric-measure-theory, mahalanobis-distance

I wonder, if some mathematician could help me please? I have this scenario (please ignore black lines):

[image]

I would like to have a metric between +1 and -1 indicating how far the curves (step functions) are away from the red line. O indicates that all curves are very close to red curve, +1 the majority are far away and above red curve and -1 the majority are far away and below red curve.

In an ideal world, I would also like to measure how much curves (not the red one) are pulled towards to left corner and lower right corner. Guess this requires an additional measure and this could not be baked into the first measure?

It may be worth pointing out that the scale of y is 0 ... 100.

Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are the curves over a finite interval or an infinite interval?  What do you want to happen if the two curves are far away, one above the other half the time and below half the time?

Comment: Thanks. Finite and discrete. Reg. above and below, that's a good point. Did not think about this ... there is a danger of zero due to cancellation out if one uses simple difference. I have no idea. Maybe use euclidean distance and somehow percentage of time above and below?